# Close(fd) not taking effect

Tags: c

My requirement is to connect with the server if it is up ,the client will keep on trying to connect with the server till the successful connection.So I have created the socket fd using the socket() and try to connect using the connect().If the connect fails ,I close the fd using the close().

The expected behaviour is, when  the next try the same file descriptor need to be generate by the socket().but for each try the new decriptor only gets created ,since I am closing the file decriptor in case of fail.What may be the issue.Can any one help me.

Comment: sometimes the connection stucks in a FIN_WAIT (or some other state), so you can't reuse this fd adhoc. try to build a concurrent server and iterate through all fd's.

Comment: @henklein: Regardless of what state the underlying connection is in, if you `close()` file descriptor it is immediately available for reuse.

Comment: You will need to post the code (preferably, a small test case that exhibits the same problem).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeatedly attempt to connect to a server until a connection is established, just use a loop around a call to connect. `socket` only binds an endpoint and a file descriptor together.

```
while (1) {
    state = connect(fd, &sa, sizeof sa);
    if (state == 0) {
        break
    } else {
        /* Is the server available yet? */
        if (errno == ECONNREFUSED) {
            /* No, continue trying to connect. */
            continue;
        } else {
             /* Deal with other errors. */
        }
    }
}
```